# Use sed to edit code

Tags: sed

How do I write a `sed` script that does the following:

`old(a,b)`

in the file should be replaced with

`new(b, 0, a)`

`a,b` can be any string with letters, spaces, digits, and these symbols: `.` `/` `*` `-` `+`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's/old(\([-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+]*\),\([-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+]*\))/new(\2, 0, \1)/'
```

Comment: I'm getting a `invalid reference \2 on s' command's RHS` error

Comment: You made a mistake.  Retrace your steps.

Comment: `[-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+]` can be substituted by `[^,]`

Comment: @Costas It cannot because the question specifies the explicit character class used in this answer.